# How can I get the values in between single or double quotes?

Tags: sed

Assuming a line like this:

```
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar
```

I would like to get the value `PGHOST` which is inside the square brackets next to the `ENV`. I assume that the line has only one such occurrence. So, this: `foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar ENV['FOO'] and foo` is not an input.

However, the line might be coming in with `"` instead of `'`, like this:

```
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar
```

In other words, the value I want to get might be enclosed in either double or single quotes.

Not only that, the actual value might contain double or single quotes. If it is enclosed in single quotes, then it can contain a double quote. If it is enclosed in double quotes, then it can contain a single quote. So, these two lines are valid expected input:

```
foo bar ENV["PGH'OST"] another bar
foo bar ENV['PGH"OST'] another bar
```

If I get lines like the above, the result should be `PGH'OST` and `PGH"OST` respectively.

I know how I can get the value if it does not contain quotes in quotes. Here it is how I do it:

```
SED_COMMAND="s/^.*ENV\[['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"]\].*$/\1/"
echo $input | sed ${SED_COMMAND}
```

So, the above works fine for `input` being `foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar` or `foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar` for example.

But it does not work for `foo bar ENV['PG"HOST'] another bar`, neither for `foo bar ENV["PG'HOST"] another bar`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Note that I don't have to solve the problem with `sed`. Any other suggestion is acceptable.

**Update**. Note that I might have inputs like this:

```
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in
```

i.e. double and/or single quotes might exist in parts of the input that are outside of the `ENV` key I want to extract.

**Update** Other example of valid input:

```
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar in NEW['YORK'] to visit
```

it can be a valid input. I need to get `PGHOST`.

And this is valid too:

```
foo bar ENV["PGH'OST"] another bar ["baz"]
```

which should return `PGH'OST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following more circumspect Bash script first removes the character after the first occurrence of ENV[ and everything before it and then removes the character before the first occurrence of ] and everything after it. Please say if you have further cases which stop this working as intended.

```
x="foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar in NEW['YORK'] to visit"; 
x=${x#*ENV[?}; x=${x%%?]*}; echo $x
```

The following version will read from a file called 'input' and write the result to a filed called 'output'.

```
cd ~/Desktop; 
while IFS= read -r x; 
do x=${x#*ENV[?}; echo ${x%%?]*} >> output;  
done < input
```

If 'input' contains:

```
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar
foo bar ENV["PGH'OST"] another bar
foo bar ENV['PGH"OST'] another bar
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar in NEW['YORK'] to visit
foo bar ENV["PGH'OST"] another bar ["baz"]
```

then the following will be written to 'output':

```
PGHOST
PGHOST
PGH'OST
PGH"OST
PGHOST
PGHOST
PGHOST
PGH'OST
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Bash script should remove:

1 - everything up to and including the first [ plus one character after it

2 - the first ] and everything after it plus one chacter before it.

```
x="foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar"; x=${x#*[?}; x=${x%%?]*}; echo $x
```

First attempt failed to display as expected until I indented 4 spaces.

Now changed to remove everyting after the first ].

I think this should work for all of your existing cases but you may wish to add more cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ SED_COMMAND="s/^.*ENV\[\(.\)\(.*\)\1\].*$/\2/"

$ cat input
foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar
foo bar ENV['PGHO"ST'] another bar
foo bar ENV["PGHO'ST"] another bar
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar

foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in
foo bar ENV["PGHOST"] another bar "what a world" I 'live' in

foo bar ENV['PGHOST'] another bar in NEW['YORK'] to visit
foo bar ENV["PGH'OST"] another bar ["baz"]


$ cat input | sed ${SED_COMMAND}
PGHOST
PGHO"ST
PGHO'ST
PGHOST

PGHOST
PGHOST

PGHOST'] another bar in NEW['YORK
PGH'OST"] another bar ["baz
```

Works for almost all your silly nonsense. Except the last two, you'll need perl to do that because [sed doesn't have non-greedy capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed), or get rid of the quotes within the square brackets and use [:alpha:] or \w.
All I changed was to assume that the quotation mark ( ' or " ) that delimits the word to be captured directly follows the opening square brace **[**, then captured the quotation mark with **.**, to catch the ' or " and used that as the ending delimiter for the \2 back reference. Then, using sed as you did, translated the entire line to only the part that you want to capture.